# Check which element was selected by selector

Tags: jquery

I'm here for a short question which is pretty simple (I think). Sorry if it's a duplicate but I can't find this question elsewhere.

I just want to know which element was selected by the selector when you select multiple elements.

For exemple :

```
$('body').on('click', '.add, .remove', function() {
    // if $(this) is a .add element, do something
    // if $(this) is a .remove element, do another thing
}
```

I can obviously create two functions, but the two will be very long and very similar so I don't want to.

I tested `$(this).is($('.add))`, `$(this).hasClass('add')` and they both didn't work.

I also tried something like :

```
$('body').on('click', '.add', foo('add'));
$('body').on('click', '.remove', foo('remove'));

function foo(which) {
    if (which == 'add')
        // do something
    else
        // do something
}
```

but I faced strange behaviours (the function is called while I don't call it etc). I think I don't fully understand how defined functions work in Javascript.

Can you help me please ?

Comment: `$(this).hasClass('add')` should work in your first version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could modify your last approach... the trouble is your are *invoking* the function when you should just be giving a function name. You can fix it like this:

```
$('body').on('click', '.add', function() {foo('add');});
$('body').on('click', '.remove', function() {foo('remove');});

function foo(which) {
    if (which == 'add')
        // do something
    else
        // do something
}
```

Comment: Okay I didn't know it worked like this... I feel like I was in my first week of jQuery haha. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

`.on()` accepts a *reference* to a callback function, you are passing in an *invocation*:

```
$foo.on('click', bar); // bar is called on click
$foo.on('click', bar()); // the *result* of calling bar is called on click
```

The second approach isn't wrong in any way, as `bar()` could be a function that returns a function (making this `(function_returned_from_bar)()`, it's just not what you need. Your approach to filtering the selectors from the body is fine and legit, so I've built on it in my proposed solution. You can read about that `event.data`-stuff going on [in the docs](https://api.jquery.com/on/).

```js
$('body').on('click', '.add', {method: 'add'}, foo);
$('body').on('click', '.remove', {method: 'remove'}, foo);

function foo(event) {

  // could also use switch/case
  if (event.data.method === 'add') {
    $('.log').append('Added<br>');
  } else {
    $('.log').append('Removed<br>');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="add">
  Add
</button>

<button class="remove">
  Remove
</button>

<div class="log"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You are selecting add and remove in a strange way, I think i may cause misbehavior
try this instead:

```
$('.add').on('click',  foo('add'));
$('.remove').on('click', foo('remove'));

 function foo(which) {
   if (which == 'add')
      // do something
  else
      // do something else
}
```

Comment: It's not strange if you need to delegate to dynamically-added elements.

Comment: The second argument to `.on()` should be a function. `foo('add')` calls the function when you're binding, it doesn't return a function.